# Cocoa bindings not working as expected? Trying to bind NSTextField's enabled to checkbox state

Tags: cocoa, binding, checkbox, nstextfield

I am simply attempting to use a checkbox to enable/disable an NSTextField. I have listed below the last method I attempted in detail, but I have attempted it multiple ways:

1. Use an NSObjectController with Content Object bound to controller and checkbox and label bound to NSObjectController selection with key path to property in controller. With and without NSIsNil Transformer.
2. No NSObjectController with checkbox and label bound to controller with key path to BOOL property in controller. With and without NSIsNil Transformer.
3. NSObjectController with Keys added and "Prepare Content" set with checkbox and label bound to NSObjectController selection and added key for key path. With and without NSIsNil Transformer.

I have gone over numerous examples and reading the documentation and have had no luck getting this working.

1. Clean project cocoa project.
2. NSObjectController "Object Controller" added to main.xib.
3. Set NSObjectController in IB to "Prepares Content"
4. Add to Keys the value "enableText".
5. Drag a checkbox and label onto view.
6. Add binding to checkbox for "Value" bound to "Object Controller", with Controller Key "selection" and Modal Key Path "enableText". At this point the auto completion reports "No completions found"! Should it not find the one I added to Object Controller???
7. Add binding to label for "Enabled" bound to "Object Controller", with Controller Key "selection" and Modal Key Path "enableText". Ditto.

Run and it crashes. If I set the label binding to have a Transformer of NSIsNil or any of the options it provides, it does not crash, but then the checkbox does not change the enabled state of the label. The crash result is below.

Of note, is that if I also add a binding between the label value and the same key as the enabled binding, then the label content does toggle between 0 and 1 when I toggle the checkbox. So, this seems like it should easily work for the enabled binding... but it isn't.

```
2012-02-20 23:43:58.273 TestBindings2[12346:903] -[_NSControllerObjectProxy copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100123540
2012-02-20 23:43:58.275 TestBindings2[12346:903] An uncaught exception was raised
2012-02-20 23:43:58.276 TestBindings2[12346:903] -[_NSControllerObjectProxy copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100123540
2012-02-20 23:43:58.278 TestBindings2[12346:903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSControllerObjectProxy copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100123540'
```

Using XCode 4.2 and OSX 10.6.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just attempted to bind the Label's "Hidden" in the exact same way as "Enabled", and it did hide it. This made me realize I was doing things correctly with binding. I attempted to manually disable the Label, and saw this did nothing. Then I saw somewhere that it says Labels are NSTextFields that are enabled, which suggests the possibility that they can not be disabled. Sure enough, changing the Label to a Text Field and the functionality works as intended.